# Menu in jQuery mobile

Tags: menu, jquery-mobile

how to create navbar menu in JQuery mobile? With 3 buttons on the top.

Comment: What kind of menu? Navbar? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

Comment: I have no idea what you want, but I'll use it as an opportunity to shamelessly advertise my own work :) http://jquerymobiledictionary.dyndns.org/dualColumn.html

Comment: @Phill Pafford  Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Could you please post it as an answer.

Comment: @naugtur It is fantastic. +1 for your work. But right now I am looking for simple 3 menu system. Thanks again for your comment

Comment: You still should edit your question so that it makes sense. Now it's too ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html